# Is it possible to use FindRoot with a function of two variables?

Tags: equation-solving

How can I use `FindRoot` with 2 variables function? Is there a different way to do that? 
For example

```
f[x_,y_]=Sin[x + y^2];
FindRoot[f[x,y], {x, -1}, {y, -3}]
```

Comment: `FindRoot[{Cos[x + y], Sin[x y]}, {x, 2}, {y, 3}]`?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I think HD2006 means functions that take 2 arguments `f[x_, y_]`.

Comment: If you have 2 unknowns, you need 2 equations, as in @AccidentialFourierTransform's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `FindRoot` to find a root of

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x + y^2]
```

because a function of two variables like `f` doesn't have roots in the sense that a function of one variable has. When a function of two variables intersects the xy-plane, it normally produces contour lines not individual points. You can examine such contours with [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html). Your function `f`, because of the oscillatory nature of `Sin` has several contours at `f[x, y] == 0` in the vicinity of $(-1,\,-3)$ as can be seen from the following plot.

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -2, 0}, {y, -4, -2},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-1, -3}]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Assume that these Contours have a minima/maxima at specific points, is it possible to find them? For example, the `ContourPlot`  of  `Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y]` has a maximum around `(-1.8,2.6)`

Comment: @HD2006. That seems to be an entirely different question concerning the finding critical points of a function of two variables. You might look at `FindMaximum`. If that doesn't work for you, I suggest posting a new question.